# Custom vertex processor doesn't work - matrix multiplication error or something else?

Tags: c++, matrix, renderer

I'm writing simple renderer in C++. It uses convention similar to OpenGL, but **it does not use OpenGL nor DirectX**. `float3, float4, float4x4` are my own custom structures.

The problem is, when I set the `eye` somewhere other then `0, 0, 0`, I get strange results with triangles where I would not expect to see them.
I guess it's because of wrong matrix multiplication formula, wrong multiplication order, normalization, or wrong formula of `lookAt/setPerspective`. But I'm stuck at it and I cannot find the mistake.

I will upload some illustrations/screens later, as I don't have access to them now.

I use column-notation for matrices (`matrix[column][row]`), like OpenGL does.

Here is the matrix multiplication code:

```
class float4x4 { //[column][row]
    float4 columns[4];

public:

    float4x4 multiplyBy(float4x4 &b){
        float4x4 c = float4x4();

        c.columns[0] = float4(
            columns[0].x * b.columns[0].x + columns[1].x * b.columns[0].y + columns[2].x * b.columns[0].z + columns[3].x * b.columns[0].w,
            columns[0].y * b.columns[0].x + columns[1].y * b.columns[0].y + columns[2].y * b.columns[0].z + columns[3].y * b.columns[0].w,
            columns[0].z * b.columns[0].x + columns[1].z * b.columns[0].y + columns[2].z * b.columns[0].z + columns[3].z * b.columns[0].w,
            columns[0].w * b.columns[0].x + columns[1].w * b.columns[0].y + columns[2].w * b.columns[0].z + columns[3].w * b.columns[0].w
            );

        c.columns[1] = float4(
            columns[0].x * b.columns[1].x + columns[1].x * b.columns[1].y + columns[2].x * b.columns[1].z + columns[3].x * b.columns[1].w,
            columns[0].y * b.columns[1].x + columns[1].y * b.columns[1].y + columns[2].y * b.columns[1].z + columns[3].y * b.columns[1].w,
            columns[0].z * b.columns[1].x + columns[1].z * b.columns[1].y + columns[2].z * b.columns[1].z + columns[3].z * b.columns[1].w,
            columns[0].w * b.columns[1].x + columns[1].w * b.columns[1].y + columns[2].w * b.columns[1].z + columns[3].w * b.columns[1].w
            );

        c.columns[2] = float4(
            columns[0].x * b.columns[2].x + columns[1].x * b.columns[2].y + columns[2].x * b.columns[2].z + columns[3].x * b.columns[2].w,
            columns[0].y * b.columns[2].x + columns[1].y * b.columns[2].y + columns[2].y * b.columns[2].z + columns[3].y * b.columns[2].w,
            columns[0].z * b.columns[2].x + columns[1].z * b.columns[2].y + columns[2].z * b.columns[2].z + columns[3].z * b.columns[2].w,
            columns[0].w * b.columns[2].x + columns[1].w * b.columns[2].y + columns[2].w * b.columns[2].z + columns[3].w * b.columns[2].w
            );

        c.columns[3] = float4(
            columns[0].x * b.columns[3].x + columns[1].x * b.columns[3].y + columns[2].x * b.columns[3].z + columns[3].x * b.columns[3].w,
            columns[0].y * b.columns[3].x + columns[1].y * b.columns[3].y + columns[2].y * b.columns[3].z + columns[3].y * b.columns[3].w,
            columns[0].z * b.columns[3].x + columns[1].z * b.columns[3].y + columns[2].z * b.columns[3].z + columns[3].z * b.columns[3].w,
            columns[0].w * b.columns[3].x + columns[1].w * b.columns[3].y + columns[2].w * b.columns[3].z + columns[3].w * b.columns[3].w
            );
        return c;
    }

    float4 multiplyBy(const float4 &b){
        //based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805126/vector-matrix-product-efficiency-issue
        float4x4 a = *this; //getTransposed(); ???
        float4 result(
            dotProduct(a[0], b),
            dotProduct(a[1], b),
            dotProduct(a[2], b),
            dotProduct(a[3], b)
            );
        return result;
    }

    inline float4x4 getTransposed() {
        float4x4 transposed;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                transposed.columns[i][j] = columns[j][i];
            }
        }
        return transposed;
    }
};
```

Where `#define dotProduct(a, b) a.getDotProduct(b)` and:

```
inline float getDotProduct(const float4 &anotherVector) const {
    return x * anotherVector.x + y * anotherVector.y + z * anotherVector.z + w * anotherVector.w;
}
```

My `VertexProcessor`:

```
class VertexProcessor {
    float4x4 obj2world;
    float4x4 world2view;
    float4x4 view2proj;
    float4x4 obj2proj;

public:
    inline float3 tr(const float3 & v) { //in object space
        float4 r = obj2proj.multiplyBy(float4(v.x, v.y, v.z, 1.0f/*v.w*/));
        return float3(r.x / r.w, r.y / r.w, r.z / r.w); //we get vector in unified cube from -1,-1,-1 to 1,1,1
    }

    inline void transform() {
        obj2proj = obj2world.multiplyBy(world2view);
        obj2proj = obj2proj.multiplyBy(view2proj);
    }

    inline void setIdentity() {
        obj2world = float4x4(
            float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
            );
    }

    inline void setPerspective(float fovy, float aspect, float nearP, float farP) {
        fovy *= PI / 360.0f;
        float fValue = cos(fovy) / sin(fovy);

        view2proj[0] = float4(fValue/aspect,    0.0f,       0.f,                                    0.0f);
        view2proj[1] = float4(0.0f,             fValue,     0.0f,                                   0.0f);
        view2proj[2] = float4(0.0f,             0.0f,       (farP + nearP) / (nearP - farP),        -1.0f);
        view2proj[3] = float4(0.0f,             0.0f,       2.0f * farP * nearP / (nearP - farP),   0.0f);
    }

    inline void setLookat(float3 eye, float3 center, float3 up) {
        float3 f = center - eye;
        f.normalizeIt();
        up.normalizeIt();
        float3 s = f.getCrossProduct(up);
        float3 u = s.getCrossProduct(f);
        world2view[0] = float4(s.x, u.x, -f.x, 0.0f);
        world2view[1] = float4(s.y, u.y, -f.y, 0.0f);
        world2view[2] = float4(s.z, u.z, -f.z, 0.0f);
        world2view[3] = float4(eye/*.getNormalized() ???*/ * -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    inline void multByTranslation(float3 v) {
        float4x4 m(
            float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(v.x, v.y, v.z, 1.0f)
            );
        world2view = m.multiplyBy(world2view);
    }

    inline void multByScale(float3 v) {
        float4x4 m(
            float4(v.x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, v.y, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 0.0f, v.z, 0.0f),
            float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
            );
        world2view = m.multiplyBy(world2view);
    }

    inline void multByRotation(float a, float3 v) {
        float s = sin(a*PI / 180.0f), c = cos(a*PI / 180.0f);
        v.normalizeIt();
        float4x4 m(
            float4(v.x*v.x*(1-c)+c,         v.y*v.x*(1 - c) + v.z*s,    v.x*v.z*(1-c)-v.y*s,    0.0f),
            float4(v.x*v.y*(1-c)-v.z*s,     v.y*v.y*(1-c)+c,            v.y*v.z*(1-c)+v.x*s,    0.0f),
            float4(v.x*v.z*(1-c)+v.y*s,     v.y*v.z*(1-c)-v.x*s,        v.z*v.z*(1-c)+c,        0.0f),
            float4(0.0f,                    0.0f,                       0.0f,                   1.0f)
            );
        world2view = m.multiplyBy(world2view);
    }
};
```

And the `Rasterizer`:

```
class Rasterizer final {
    Buffer * buffer = nullptr;

    inline float toScreenSpaceX(float x) { return (x + 1) * buffer->getWidth() * 0.5f; }
    inline float toScreenSpaceY(float y) { return (y + 1) * buffer->getHeight() * 0.5f; }

    inline int orient2d(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by, const float2& c) {
        return (bx - ax)*(c.y - ay) - (by - ay)*(c.x - ax);
    }

public:
    Rasterizer(Buffer * buffer) : buffer(buffer) {}
    //v - position in screen space ([0, width], [0, height], [-1, -1])
    void triangle(
        float3 v0, float3 v1, float3 v2,
        float3 n0, float3 n1, float3 n2,
        float2 uv0, float2 uv1, float2 uv2, 
        Light * light0, Light * light1,
        float3 camera, Texture * texture
        ) {

        v0.x = toScreenSpaceX(v0.x);
        v0.y = toScreenSpaceY(v0.y);
        v1.x = toScreenSpaceX(v1.x);
        v1.y = toScreenSpaceY(v1.y);
        v2.x = toScreenSpaceX(v2.x);
        v2.y = toScreenSpaceY(v2.y);

        //based on: https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/triangle-rasterization-in-practice/

        //compute triangle bounding box
        int minX = MIN3(v0.x, v1.x, v2.x);
        int minY = MIN3(v0.y, v1.y, v2.y);
        int maxX = MAX3(v0.x, v1.x, v2.x);
        int maxY = MAX3(v0.y, v1.y, v2.y);

        //clip against screen bounds
        minX = MAX(minX, 0);
        minY = MAX(minY, 0);
        maxX = MIN(maxX, buffer->getWidth() - 1);
        maxY = MIN(maxY, buffer->getHeight() - 1);

        //rasterize
        float2 p(0.0f, 0.0f);
        for (p.y = minY; p.y <= maxY; p.y++) {
            for (p.x = minX; p.x <= maxX; p.x++) {
                // Determine barycentric coordinates
                //int w0 = orient2d(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y, p);
                //int w1 = orient2d(v2.x, v2.y, v0.x, v0.y, p);
                //int w2 = orient2d(v0.x, v0.y, v1.x, v1.y, p);

                float w0 = (v1.y - v2.y)*(p.x - v2.x) + (v2.x - v1.x)*(p.y - v2.y);
                w0 /= (v1.y - v2.y)*(v0.x - v2.x) + (v2.x - v1.x)*(v0.y - v2.y);
                float w1 = (v2.y - v0.y)*(p.x - v2.x) + (v0.x - v2.x)*(p.y - v2.y);
                w1 /= (v2.y - v0.y)*(v1.x - v2.x) + (v0.x - v2.x)*(v1.y - v2.y);
                float w2 = 1 - w0 - w1;

                // If p is on or inside all edges, render pixel.
                if (w0 >= 0 && w1 >= 0 && w2 >= 0) {
                    float depth = w0 * v0.z + w1 * v1.z + w2 * v2.z;
                    if (depth < buffer->getDepthForPixel(p.x, p.y)) {
                        //...
                        buffer->setPixel(p.x, p.y, diffuse.r, diffuse.g, diffuse.b, ALPHA_VISIBLE, depth);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
};
```

I strongly believe that **`Rasterizer` itself works well** , because when I test it with code (instead of main loop):

```
float3 v0{ 0, 0, 0.1f };
float3 v1{ 0.5, 0, 0.1f };
float3 v2{ 1, 1, 0.1f }; 
//Rasterizer test (without VertexProcessor)
rasterizer->triangle(v0, v1, v2, n0, n1, n2, uv0, uv1, uv2, light0, light1, eye, defaultTexture);
```

I get the right image, with triangle that has one corner at the middle of the screen (`[0, 0]` in unified space), one at bottom-right corner (`[1, 1]`) and one at `[0.5, 0]`.

The `float3` structure:

```
class float3 {
public:
    union {
        struct { float x, y, z; };
        struct { float r, g, b; };
        float p[3];
    };

    float3() = delete;
    float3(const float3 &other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {}
    float3(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    float &operator[](unsigned index){
        ERROR_HANDLE(index < 3, L"The float3 index out of bounds (0-2 range, " + C::toWString(index) + L" given).");
        return p[index];
    }

    float getLength() const { return std::abs(sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)); }
    void normalizeIt();
    inline float3 getNormalized() const {
        float3 result(*this);
        result.normalizeIt();
        return result;
    }   
    inline float3 getCrossProduct(const float3 &anotherVector) const {
        //based on: http://www.sciencehq.com/physics/vector-product-multiplying-vectors.html
        return float3(
            y * anotherVector.z - anotherVector.y * z,
            z * anotherVector.x - anotherVector.z * x,
            x * anotherVector.y - anotherVector.x * y
            );
    }
    inline float getDotProduct(const float3 &anotherVector) const {
        //based on: https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/Vectors/DOTCROS.HTM
        return x * anotherVector.x + y * anotherVector.y + z * anotherVector.z;
    } 
    ...
};
```

The main loop:

```
VertexProcessor vp;

DirectionalLight * light0 = new DirectionalLight({ 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f }, { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f });
DirectionalLight * light1 = new DirectionalLight({ 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f }, { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f });

while(!my_window.is_closed()) {

    tgaBuffer.clearDepth(10.0f); //it could be 1.0f but 10.0f won't hurt, we draw pixel if it's depth < actual depth in buffer
    tgaBuffer.clearColor(0, 0, 255, ALPHA_VISIBLE);

    vp.setPerspective(75.0f, tgaBuffer.getWidth() / tgaBuffer.getHeight(), 10.0f, 2000.0f);

    float3 eye = { 10.0f, 10.0f - frameTotal / 10.0f, 10.0f }; //animate eye

    vp.setLookat(eye, float3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }.getNormalized(), { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f });

    vp.setIdentity();
    //we could call e.g. vp.multByRotation(...) here, but we won't to keep it simple
    vp.transform();

    //bottom
    drawTriangle(0, 1, 2);
    drawTriangle(2, 3, 0);

    drawTriangle(3, 2, 7);
    drawTriangle(7, 2, 6);

    drawTriangle(5, 1, 0);
    drawTriangle(0, 5, 4);

    drawTriangle(4, 5, 6);
    drawTriangle(6, 7, 4);

    frameTotal++;
}
```

Where `drawTriangle(...)` stands for:

```
#define drawTriangle(i0, i1, i2) rasterizer->triangle(vp.tr(v[i0]), vp.tr(v[i1]), vp.tr(v[i2]), v[i0], v[i1], v[i2], n0, n1, n2, uv0, uv1, uv2, light0, light1, eye, defaultTexture);
```

And here is the initialization of triangles' data:

```
float3 offset{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
v.push_back(offset + float3{ -10, -10, -10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ +10, -10, -10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ +10, -10, +10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ -10, -10, +10 });

v.push_back(offset + float3{ -10, +10, -10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ +10, +10, -10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ +10, +10, +10 });
v.push_back(offset + float3{ -10, +10, +10 });
```

Comment: In `setPerspective` you are using `fovy *= PI / 360.0f;` but shouldn't it be ` fovy *= PI / 180.0f;` ?

Comment: @Gene Aren't I taking it into account later in `setPerspective(...)` formula (not multiplying by 2 etc.)?

Comment: Yeah, this could very likely be true. Just didn't notice, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a little c-library for opengl long time ago. It was generally for learning purpose during my studies of computer graphics. I've looked up my sources and my implementation of perspective projection and orientation very much differs.

```
pbm_Mat4 pbm_mat4_projection_perspective(PBfloat fov, PBfloat ratio, PBfloat near, PBfloat far) {
    PBfloat t = near * tanf(fov / 2.0f);
    PBfloat b = -t;
    PBfloat r = ratio * t, l = ratio * b;
    return pbm_mat4_create(pbm_vec4_create(2.0f * near / (r - l), 0, 0, 0),
                           pbm_vec4_create(0, 2.0f * near / (t - b), 0, 0),
                           pbm_vec4_create((r + l) / (r - l), (t + b) / (t - b), - (far + near) / (far - near), -1.0f),
                           pbm_vec4_create(0, 0, -2.0f * far * near / (far - near), 0));
}

pbm_Mat4 pbm_mat4_orientation_lookAt(pbm_Vec3 pos, pbm_Vec3 target, pbm_Vec3 up) {
    pbm_Vec3 forward = pbm_vec3_normalize(pbm_vec3_sub(target, pos));
    pbm_Vec3 right = pbm_vec3_normalize(pbm_vec3_cross(forward, up));
    up = pbm_vec3_normalize(pbm_vec3_cross(right, forward));
    forward = pbm_vec3_scalar(forward, -1);
    pos = pbm_vec3_scalar(pos, -1);
    return pbm_mat4_create(pbm_vec4_create_vec3(right),
                           pbm_vec4_create_vec3(up),
                           pbm_vec4_create_vec3(forward),
                           pbm_vec4_create_vec3_w(pbm_vec3_create(pbm_vec3_dot(right, pos),
                                                  pbm_vec3_dot(up, pos),     
                                                  pbm_vec3_dot(forward, pos)), 1));
}
```

These methods are tested and you may want to test against them. Iff you want full sources are availabe [here](http://snippets.breakingbit.com/?2). Furthermore you could revisit frustums and projection matrices [online](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx). Unfortanetly I can not share the material from my university with you:(

Comment: I've changed the orientation/projection code according to your. It changes but still - when I animate the eye (`pos`) around `0,0,0` target I don't see camera rotating around the point. Instead my objects animate from left to right side of screen and then again from right to left. And they are somehow scaled (squeezed).

Comment: from your code the animation behavior seems as expected `float3 eye = { 10.0f, 10.0f - frameTotal / 10.0f, 10.0f }; //animate eye`. Do you have some screenshots or a small testproject you can share? It is kinda hard to work threw all the code without expectations.