# How to sum a vector elements using AVX?

Tags: c, x86, intrinsics, avx

I want to sum all 32bit element in a 256 register but there isn't any intrinsics instruction or if there is I couldn't help what I want. So I did some thing like this to sum but this method generates many assembly instruction when compiled.

My method :

```
_mm256_store_ps(&temp4[0], sum0_i); 
            c_result[i][j]= temp4[0]+temp4[1]+temp4[2]+temp4[3]+temp4[4]+temp4[5]+temp4[6]+temp4[7];
```

Assembly output:

```
    vmovaps %ymm0, (%rsp)
    vmovss  (%rsp), %xmm0
    vaddss  4(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  8(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  12(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  16(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  20(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  24(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vaddss  28(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovss  %xmm0, c_result(%r8,%rsi)
```

So the question is how can I sum all elements faster and more professional and store them to the 32 bit array in memory? I tried `hadd` but didn't improve the performance. because I still have memory problem to save them and also `hadd` latency and throughput killing the time more than `vaddss`

Comment: [horizontal sum of 8 packed 32bit floats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13879609/995714), [How to sum __m256 horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219146/995714), [Horizontal sum of 32-bit floats in 256-bit AVX vector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23189488/995714)

Comment: I read and tried them but the speedup didn't change

Comment: @ADMS If the answers to the referenced questions don't seed your code up, this is probably not your bottleneck. Why are you optimizing non time-critical code?

Comment: @ADMS: The 93-fold speedup, to me, suggests the optimizer is just removing the whole code if you comment out this part, since the rest of the code probably has no semantically visible side effects.

Comment: Good point, but I still have that problem with latency of `hadd` and other thing in the question.

Comment: OK I will find the answer and share here.

Comment: Start with `_mm256_extractf128_ps`, `_mm_add_ps` the two halves together, then use [the existing methods for reducing a 128b vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86).

Comment: Does it cost any penalty exchanging between `AVX` to `SSE` or vise versa ?

Answer (score 0):

You might start with the code any optimizing compiler generates for vectorized sum reduction with or without accumulate(), cilkplus reducer, or omp simd reduction.  No doubt there is a step adding 128 bit sub registers, one with hadd, and so on.