# C style cast versus intrinsic cast

Tags: c, sse, avx

Let's assume i have defined `__m256d x` and that I want to extract the lower 128-bits.  I would do:

```
__m128d xlow = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x);
```

However, I recently saw someone do:

```
__m128d xlow = (__m128d) x
```

Is there a prefered method to use for the cast?  Why use the first method?

Comment: The second one is not standard*. It looks like a GCC extension. MSVC rejects it. (*And by "not standard" I mean Intel does not specify it in the intrinsics specification. All of this is already non-standard as far as C/C++ goes.)

Comment: Does that cast work with gcc? The doc explicitly says it doesn't, so it looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks Mysicical.  That's what I suspected.  I saw it used at [fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-vector-sum-with-avx-instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775538/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-vector-sum-with-avx-instructions/20389775#20389775)

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I have not tested the second case with any compiler.  I just saw it used in the answer to the question above.